# Find combinations in multiple data sets

Tags: r, matching

I'm currently working on the project where I have about multiple CSV files need to match all combinations of events people attended by matching their customer id. They have been to multiple events. I need the events matched in a new column separated by comma. There is multiple data sets that need to be compared. Vlookup in excel was freezing due to the amount of data. How can I do this in R?  I have tidyverse already installed. Any suggestions?

```
 List 1   (one CSV file)                          List 2 (second CSV file)
LastName FirstName     CustID  Event         LastName FirstName CustID Event 
Robson     Jonson       23019   NP5          Robson   Jonson    23019   GRT2 
Robson     Jonson       23019   RTE3

Result Needed
LastName  FirstName      CustID     Matched Events     
Rob       Jonson         23019      NPS, GRT2, RTE3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your datasets are identically-structured, so they can be combined row-wise with `rbind`:

```
lst1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text='
LastName FirstName     CustID  Event
Robson     Jonson       23019   NP5 
Robson     Jonson       23019   RTE3')

lst2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text='
LastName FirstName CustID Event 
Robson   Jonson    23019   GRT2')

lst <- rbind(lst1, lst2)
```

Then you need an aggregation:

```
aggregate(lst$Event,
          list(LastName = lst$LastName, FirstName = lst$FirstName, CustID = lst$CustID),
          paste, collapse=", ")
#   LastName FirstName CustID               x
# 1   Robson    Jonson  23019 NP5, RTE3, GRT2
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to use the loaded CSV files. If I enter the amount of data as txt in R it freezes.

Comment: *"need to use the loaded CSV files"* ... this code is using files already read into R. The two calls to `read.table` are to make reproducible data, since the question was a little hard to read-in automatically. Skip those calls and start up with `rbind`.